# How do I call an object/constructor to return a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, operator-overloading

I have been given the following code in my test file to implement:

```
cout << "Testing the Matrix constructors:" << endl;

cout << "Case 1: Creating a 2x4 matrix of zeros with the standard constructor:" << endl;
{
    Matrix matrix(2, 4);
    cout << matrix << endl;
```

Currently my code in my .cpp file for the constructor is as follows:

```
Matrix::Matrix (const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols){

double **p_matrix = new double*[noOfRows];
for(int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
    p_matrix[i] = new double[noOfCols];
}

for(int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<noOfCols; j++){
        p_matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

My main confusion is the cout<< matrix part of the code as I could print out my 2x4 matrix within my constructor without needing this line.  However, I have been asked to include cout<< matrix and I'm not sure I understand how it is meant to work.  Is it calling my object matrix?  And if so, how do I return my 2D array p_matrix since I'm not able to return a value from a constructor?

I thought one solution might be to overload my << operator as shown below:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix& rhs){
output << rhs.data << std::endl;
return output; }
```

The reason I put rhs.data is because I tried rhs.matrix and rhs.p_matrix but got an error that a member variable was needed.  Within my .h file, the only member variables I'm allowed are as follows:

1. int noOfRows: the member variable that stores the number of rows
2. int noOfColumns: the member variable that stores the number of columns
3. double *data: the member variable that stores the address to the 1-D array of the matrix entries arranged column-wise, i.e., 1st column followed by the 2nd column and so on and so
   forth
4. int GetIndex (const int rowIdx, const int columnIdx) const: the member
   function that determines the position (index) along the 1-D array (data) of a matrix entry in the row specified by rowIdx and the column specified by columnIdx.

I'm unsure how I can use operator overloading using only these variables so is this the best solution or is there an alternative way? Considering the limitations that I can't change my test file or the 4 member variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say:

> Within my .h file, the only member variables I'm allowed are ... double *data: the member variable that stores the address to the 1-D array of the matrix

So, `Matrix` constructor should initialize `data` attribute, not a local `double **p_matrix` variable (then leaving `data` uninitialized)...

Simply replace:

```
Matrix::Matrix (const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols)
{
    double **p_matrix = new double*[noOfRows];
    for(int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
        p_matrix[i] = new double[noOfCols];
    }

    for(int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<noOfCols; j++){
            p_matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

By:

**1. If your `data` attribute is a `double**`**

```
Matrix::Matrix (const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols)
{

    this->noOfRows = noOfRows;
    this->noOfCols = noOfCols; 

    data = new double*[noOfRows];
    for(int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
        data[i] = new double[noOfCols];
    }

    for(int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<noOfCols; j++){
            data[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Later, you can do:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix& rhs)
{
    for( int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
        for( int j=0; j < noOfCols; j++){
            output << rhs.data[i][j] << " "; // next column
        }
        output << std::endl; // next line
    }
    return output; 
}
```

**2. If your `data` attribute is a `double*`**

```
Matrix::Matrix (const int noOfRows, const int noOfCols){

    this->noOfRows = noOfRows;
    this->noOfCols = noOfCols;

    data = new double[noOfRows*noOfCols];
    for(int i=0; i< noOfRows*noOfCols; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Later, you can do:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix& rhs)
{
    for( int i=0; i< noOfRows; i++){
        for( int j=0; j < noOfCols; j++){
            output << rhs.data[noOfCols*i+j] << " "; // next column
        }
        output << std::endl; // next line
    }
    return output; 
}
```

In both cases, make sure `data` is public in your header file, or make `operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix& rhs)` be a `friend` of `Matrix` (or add a getter).

By the way, note that matrix are commonly stored as a `double*` rather than `double**`.

Comment: I'm still getting an error "cannot convert 'double**' to 'double*' in assignment" since I need to have data as double* originally so that's why I created p_matrix.  Is there any way to de-reference my double** p_matrix and make it correspond to double* data?

Comment: No way, you can't convert a `double**` to `double*`. I edited my post to show how you should do depending if your attribute is a `double*` or a `double**`

Comment: Thanks, I've got the data part working but noOfRows and noOfCols aren't working properly in the operator<< which I've made to be a friend of Matrix.  When I do rhs.noOfRows I think it is taking the original value from my header file which is not defined.  When I simply use noOfRows it says it is not declared in this scope even though the operator is a friend and appears after it was used as an input for my constructor.  Do I need an extra line in my constructor to match up my original noOfRows variable in my header function with the input to my constructor?

Comment: Wow...first time writting C++...? ;-) All your attributes must be initialized. I edited my post, you need to set the `noOfRows` and `noOfCols` or `noOfColumns`(whatever name it has) object attributes upon construction.

Comment: Yeah it works now, figured it out shortly after I posted!  Can you edit your post so that 1) refers to double** and 2) refers to double* just to avoid confusion as they both say double** right now?  Also, do you know any way I can use the same <<operator function for a static member function i.e. (Matrix matrix = Matrix::Zeros(2,4);
cout<<matrix<<endl;) within the test .cpp and still using the data as a double* variable?

Comment: Edited my post to fix the typo. For your last question, why don't you simply do cout  << Matrix::Zeros(2,4)?

Comment: I have got it working by simply writing (Matrix out(noOfRows, noOfCols); return out) and then it works as before.  The only problem is I don't know how to change this for using a static member function of ones instead of zeros with (Matrix matrix = Matrix::Ones(2,4);)

Comment: That's a different issue, please post a different question.